# JavaScript - Elementos HTML dinamicamente

Tags: javascript, html5, front-end, dinâmico

Criar elementos HTML dinamicamente pelo JAVASCRIPT é uma prática ruim? Por exemplo:

```js
var img = document.createElement('img')
img.setAttribute('id', 'foto')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Criar elementos dinamicamente é muito comum. Não é má prática, pelo contrário.

O que pode ser problemático é caso esses elementos não forem removidos adequadamente e fiquem em memória causando problemas de performance.

Se adicionares propriedades a esses objetos deves depois fazer `delete div.algumaPropriedade`, ou pelo menos `div.algumaPropriedade = null;`.  Atributos como estás a usar não são problema, é mais no caso de funções, objetos ou arrays pesadas que fiquem associadas a partes desse elemento e que não são por vezes removidas quando usas `parent.removeChild(div);`.